# What are the limitations of C++ running on the iPhone?

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c

I like C++ a lot and to be honest the Objective-C "super set" of C is more of a "super fail".  Can an iPhone application be written in pure C++?  Are there parts of the API that are unavailable from C++?

Comment: Apple REALLY isn't friendly toward apps being written in ways they don't approve. My guess is that you'd have even more than the usual approval troubles if you do this and try to get into the app store.

Comment: That's silly, a large portion of the games written for iPhone are already mainly C++, XCode supports C++ out of the box.

Comment: @Michael Kohne: If I could down-vote your comment I would. Completely false.

Comment: I just read a bit im the Objective-C documentation: you're so right! It really seems like a bad, bad super fail! And this was just after reading how to best name messages/methods!!!

Comment: How ironic... "There are only two kinds of languages: the ones people complain about and the ones nobody uses. — Bjarne Stroustrup (Creator of C++)" Just an FYI, insulting a language as you're asking for help is unlikely to yield the most ideal results. I personally strongly dislike C++, but if I were to call it a "super fail" while asking how to write in Objective-C instead, I'd be flamed to scorn. Including only what is relevant to the question makes for a better question. :-)

Comment: I'm a paid C++ programmer and it is a powerful language.  However,  C++ is not my favorite language,  its not even in my top 5.   Python is by far my favorite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't code purely in C++. For one, the UIApplicationDelegate class every application needs to inherit is Objective-C.

However, nothing is stopping you from coding everything that isn't framework related in Objective-C++. You'll still need to use the Objective-C calls for UIKit and other frameworks, but all of your application logic can be in C++.

From the [Objective-C++ section](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH10-SW1) of the Objective-C programming guide, these are the main limitations:

> Objective-C++ does not add C++
>   features to Objective-C classes, nor
>   does it add Objective-C features to
>   C++ classes. For example, you cannot
>   use Objective-C syntax to call a C++
>   object, you cannot add constructors or
>   destructors to an Objective-C object,
>   and you cannot use the keywords this
>   and self interchangeably. The class
>   hierarchies are separate; a C++ class
>   cannot inherit from an Objective-C
>   class, and an Objective-C class cannot
>   inherit from a C++ class. In addition,
>   multi-language exception handling is
>   not supported. That is, an exception
>   thrown in Objective-C code cannot be
>   caught in C++ code and, conversely, an
>   exception thrown in C++ code cannot be
>   caught in Objective-C code. For more
>   information on exceptions in
>   Objective-C, see “Exception Handling.”

Comment: The part about exceptions only applies to 32-bit Mac code. In iPhone and 64-bit Mac code, the two languages use the same mechanism for exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Some Carbon APIs exist in the iPhone so you will be able to access them from within a purely c++ application. That being said, however, there are a lot of very important APIs that are Objective-C only (e.g., UIKit). With some good design decisions a reasonable C/C++ shim could be written to encapsulate the Objective-C necessary to get an iPhone application working. Once that's done you'd be able to write your app with traditional C++ no problem.

The way Objective-C++ is set up you can still write bona fide C++ and mix-in Objective-C calls where necessary. This has been the route I've taken in the iPhone applications I have developed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you'll manage to completely escape objective-c for any meaningful application, but you are free to code mostly in C++. In fact, sio2(one of the iphone game engines) is mostly C++ if you were to use that as the base for your application you could probably avoid writing objective-c yourself.

I would like to know what you don't like about objective-c? I came from a C++ background and find Obj-C to be refreshing and more OO than C++.

Comment: I like some of the ideas (like runtime typing) although I would most like it as an extension to a statically typed language. But what seems absolutely crude to me is the language itswlf. Very ugly and message/method names for methods with parameters is a real pain.

Comment: C is a statically typed language.

I'd suggest playing around with Objective-C for a while, coming from C++ the brackets were a little hard to get used to, but now I love the syntax. I feel that my code is much more expressive than in the other languages that I've used.

Comment: @jessecurry: You're right: C is a statically typed language. What I really meant was: I would like it as an extension to a statically types, object-oriented language :-)

Answer (score 1):

You only need to do the GUI in Obj-C (Obj-C++).

There is no problem with integrating any other C++ code with the interface. Just be carefully to manually delete your pointers that are held inside Obj-C objects